# code in discord.py does not recognize two simultaneous events

Tags: python, discord

I'm making a bot for my friends' discord, it is a calculator and it must also answer some keywords with some jokes, the problem is that, it works like a calculator normally, but when I add the event that answers the keywords with jokes , the calculator stops working and only the jokes are sent. the calculator looks like this:

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='&', help_command=None)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('on')

def raizes(a: float, b: float, c: float):
    return (-b + math.sqrt((b ** 2) - 4 * a * c)) / 2 * a, (-b - math.sqrt((b ** 2) - 4 * a * c)) / 2 * a


@client.command()
async def matraizes(ctx, a: float, b: float, c: float):
    res = raizes(a, b, c)
    await ctx.send(res)
```

and then as soon as I add this event, it stops working:

```
@client.event  
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.lower().startswith('test'):
        await message.channel.send('ok')
```

Comment: If you use the `on_message` event you'll have to invoke the commands yourself, as you have replaced the default logic for parsing and invoking the commands.

Answer (score 0):

Before adding the on message event, discord.py already has its default on message event - which is used to process the commands. Now you created your own event, it overwrites the default on message event, but this can be easily fixed because all you have to do is to process the commands again.

```py
@client.event  
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.lower().startswith('test'):
        await message.channel.send('ok')
    
    await client.process_commands(message)
```